# Formatting HTTP Response Headers in tcl

Tags: tcl, httpresponse

I just started messing with tcl tonight and I've hit my first hurdle. Here is my code:

```
package require http
package require tls

::http::register https 443 ::tls::socket

set url https://127.0.0.1:8834/session
set body [http::formatQuery username admin password myPassword]
set login [http::geturl $url -query $body]
set authToken [http::data $login]

http::cleanup $token
```

This is how authToken looks after the code runs:

```
% puts $authToken
{"token":"d52e61030d93824128cea67e2b99dde6f3fd61b25e9a0440"}
```

I only need d52e61030d93824128cea67e2b99dde6f3fd61b25e9a0440 stored.  I cannot figure out how to do this.

I tried using the rest package, but I couldn't get that to work either:

```
package require rest
package require tls

::http::register https 443 ::tls::socket

set nessus(login) {
    url https://127.0.0.1:8834/session
    method POST
    req_args {username: password:}
}

rest::create_interface nessus

set token [nessus::login -username admin -password myPassword]
```

Here is my output from running this code:

```
% puts $token
token ba9c5b4256ef701bf7d8ae151c01261cb8a3267f1b8c2787
```

This may be a bit easier to format than the http code, I'm assuming.

In Python I was able to retrieve *just* that token key by pulling 'token' out of the json but I'm not sure how to accomplish that in tcl.

Comment: Great start with Tcl. I'd be interested in hearing about your motivation for learning it, and your impressions of the language.

Comment: @glennjackman a customer called in on Thursday looking for support with our API. I've got a pretty decent understanding of the API with curl and Python and just wanted to help out the customer.  Figures it would make a good weekend project :).  As for my impressions, I'm enjoying it so far, and I think I'll really enjoy it once I pick up some more syntax. I enjoy keeping all of my calls organized into their own method, still struggling with that in tcl but I'll get the hang of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The response you are getting is in the form of a json object, with one key and one value. You can use the `json` package to turn it into a Tcl `dict` structure:

```
package require json
::json::json2dict [http::data $login]
# -> token d52e61030d93824128cea67e2b99dde6f3fd61b25e9a0440
```

The `rest` package autodetects xml and json, and apparently converts the object received into a `dict` before delivering it.

You can get the value by normal dictionary access:

```
dict get $token token
# -> ba9c5b4256ef701bf7d8ae151c01261cb8a3267f1b8c2787
# or
dict get [::json::json2dict [http::data $login]] token
# -> d52e61030d93824128cea67e2b99dde6f3fd61b25e9a0440
```

The `lindex` command could also be used, but it's probably better practice in the long run to use dictionary access.

Documentation: [dict](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/dict.htm), [http](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/http.htm), [json](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/json/json.html) package, [lindex](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lindex.htm), [package](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/package.htm)

Comment: This worked perfectly!  Having some issues getting further commands to work with the token, but the important part is that I got it stored.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code:

```
package require rest
package require tls

::http::register https 443 ::tls::socket

set nessus(login) {
    url https://127.0.0.1:8834/session
    method POST
    req_args {username: password:}
}
rest::create_interface nessus
set token [lindex [nessus::login -username admin -password myPassword] 1]
```

Comment: I could only mark one of these correct but I wanted to let you know that yours also worked for the rest portion of my code!